# Fetch the mongo result between the provided multiple date ranges

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem. I need to fetch the records from MongoDB and plot them in a graph. I need to fetch data in such a manner that records from mongo are fetched in the date ranges right from the MongoDB. Date ranges would be like this

```
1.    start date 2018-07-10 05:00:00,  end date: 2018-07-11 04:59:59
2.    start date 2018-07-11 05:00:00,  end date: 2018-07-12 04:59:59
3.    start date 2018-07-12 05:00:00,  end date: 2018-07-13 04:59:59
4.    start date 2018-07-13 05:00:00,  end date: 2018-07-14 04:59:59
```

Data Sample:

```
    {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5b488f7631b9a41d733d5360"),
       "user" : 8,
       "event" : 2,
       "checkedIn" : 0,
       "TotalTime" : 235,
       "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213,
       "user_event" : [ 
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-13T11:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           },
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-12T00:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           },
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-10T11:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           }
       ]
    },
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("5b488f7631b9a41d733d5360"),
       "user" : 8,
       "event" : 3,
       "checkedIn" : 0,
       "TotalTime" : 235,
       "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213,
       "user_event" : [ 
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-13T11:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           },
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-12T00:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           },
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-10T11:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           }
       ]
    },
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("5b488f7631b9a41d733d5360"),
       "user" : 10,
       "event" : 2,
       "checkedIn" : 0,
       "TotalTime" : 235,
       "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213,
       "user_event" : [ 
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-13T11:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           },
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-12T00:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           },
           {
               "date" : ISODate("2018-07-10T11:43:33.496Z"),
               "totalTime" : 235,
               "CheckedInAt" : 1531482213
           }
       ]
    }
```

Here `user_event` is the sub document which keeps the record for specific user with specified event id. If the user participate in same event again then their records are piled up in `user_event` sub document. I want to fetch these records.

I need these records to be fetched in the order the dates are provided to them. For example if the data lies beteen date 4 then the date start date and end date included in the result along with the data the lies between them.
This is my current aggregate query (Mongodb 3.4). Its giving me the record array with in date format `%Y-%m-%d`. and `event_attended_date` containing all the dates for specific data in the above date format

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate(
     {
            "$unwind": "$user_event"
        }, {
            "$match": {
                "$and": [{
                        "user_event.date": {
                            "$lte": ISODate('2018-07-14T04:59:590Z'),
                            "$gte": ISODate('2018-07-10T05:00:000Z')
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "event": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "$match": {
                "user": {
                    "$nin": [1, 2]
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                        "date": "$user_event.date"
                    }
                },
                "TotalTime": {
                    "$sum": "$user_event.TotalTime"
                },
                "userAttended": {
                    "$sum": 1
                },
                "event_attended_date": {
                    "$push": "$user_event.date"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "$project": {
                "date": "$_id",
                "TotalTime": 1,
                "userAttended": 1,
                "event_attended_date": 1
            }
        });
```

This is my current output (Showing lesser records ). I want each /* record */ contain the records in the provided date ranges. Is it possible?

```
  /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-07-10",
    "TotalTime" : 2436,
    "userAttended" : 3.0,
    "event_attended_date" : [ 
        ISODate("2018-07-10T02:46:32.861Z"), 
        ISODate("2018-07-10T01:36:50.799Z"), 
        ISODate("2018-07-10T00:47:35.402Z")
    ],
    "date" : "2018-07-10"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-07-09",
    "TotalTime" : 145,
    "userAttended" : 2.0,
    "event_attended_date" : [ 
        ISODate("2018-07-09T15:43:24.071Z"), 
        ISODate("2018-07-09T20:23:22.205Z")
    ],
    "date" : "2018-07-09"
}
```

I want records to show up like this

```
{
        "_id" : "2018-07-09",
        "TotalTime" : 145, -- sum of their total time
        "userAttended" : 4, -- sum of unique user attended
        "event_attended_date" : [ -- if the above 2 records are accurate then I don't need this element.
            ISODate("2018-07-09T15:43:24.071Z"), 
            ISODate("2018-07-09T20:23:22.205Z")
        ],
        "startDate" : "2018-07-09 05:00:00",
        "endDate" : "2018-07-10 04:59:59",

    }
```

Later I am going to manipulate these records using PHP as backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to find records in a collection filtering by a date range

```
Collection.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

Comment: Already mentioned, I don't need to find the record in this specified range, I need to find records in multiple date ranges. For that, we use `aggregate` method instead of `find` method.